# How to join items of multidimensional array using php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, implode

I have an array as shown bottom

```
array (
    [det1] => 1,2,3,4 
    [det2] => 5,6
);
```

So i want to join items of this array and convert array to an string like bottom

```
$uru = 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

How can i do this work?

Comment: If you need more advanced snippet, please go through [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Possible Duplicate (assuming the title is correct and the input data is wrong): https://stackoverflow.com/q/1319903/2943403

Answer (score 4):

Did you try like this with `implode()`

```
<?php
$arr = array('det1'=>'1,2,3,4', 'det2'=>'5,6');
$uru = implode(',',$arr);
echo $uru;
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/UBQrv

Answer (score 3):

You say multidimensional array, but your array is single dimensional with strings?
I assume that is a typo and your array is multidimensional.

In that case loop the array and merge the new array with the subarray.

```
$arr = array (
    "det1" => [1,2,3,4],
    "det2" => [5,6]
);

$new= [];
foreach($arr as $sub){
    $new = array_merge($new, $sub);
}

echo implode(",",$new); // 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

https://3v4l.org/NaDXN

Comment: This can also be done without `array_merge` like `$new .= implode(',', $sub)` .

Comment: @Smartpal No it return `1,2,3,45,6`

Comment: @Mohammad  Yes, it return, you can add extra `,` at end of function like this `implode(','$sub).',';` then use `rtrim` to remove last one.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done by extracting into array_merge and then joining the resulting array.

```
$data = [
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [6,7,8],
];

echo join(',', array_merge(... $data));
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

Comment: Good idea, but this won't work because `$data` has string keys, and you can't unpack an array with string keys. It should work if you used `array_values` on `$data`.